# Extension of the lifetime of a temporary with an rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-semantics

[According to another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3716360/150634), an rvalue reference will not extend the lifetime of a temporary if the expression referring to it is an xvalue expression. Since `std::move` returns an rvalue reference, the expression of calling it is an xvalue and so the following results in an a dangling reference:

```
int main()
{
  std::string&& danger = std::move(get_string());  // dangling reference !
  return 0;
}
```

That's fine. The `std::move` doesn't make sense here; it is already an rvalue.

But here's where I'm drawing a blank. How is this different to passing an xvalue expression as an argument, completely standard use of `std::move` and rvalue references?

```
void foo(const std::string& val);
// More efficient foo for temporaries:
void foo(std::string&& val);

int main()
{
  std::string s;
  foo(std::move(s)); // Give up s for efficiency
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a special rule for rvalue reference arguments that will extend the lifetime of a temporary regardless of whether it is an prvalue or xvalue? Or is the `std::move` calling expression only an xvalue because we passed it something that was already an rvalue? I don't think so because it returns an rvalue reference anyway, which is an xvalue. I'm confused here. I think I'm missing something silly.

Comment: Unrelated: if the function `foo` is going to copy or move either way, you may want to just take the argument by value and let the compiler do the copy or move.

Comment: A note about your first example: `std::move(get_string())` is no longe a temporary expression. The temporary expression was `get_string()`, but then you cast it. So the rule about a temporary expression binding to a reference no longer applies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to extend any lifetime here: the object in question lasts until the end of `main`, which is after the end of `foo`.

Comment: Indeed... there aren't even any temporaries in the given code.

Answer (score 9):

Your second example is not passing a reference to a temporary, it's passing a reference to the variable `s`, which lasts until the end of `main()`.

If it were (e.g. `foo(std::move(get_string()));`), then the temporary's lifetime lasts until the end of the full expression - after the function has returned. It's therefore quite safe to use it within `foo`. There is only a danger if `foo` stores a reference/pointer to its argument, and something else tries to use it later.

Comment: But it is illegal to take addresses of rvalues.

Comment: @user1095108 but `val` is not an rvalue within the body of the function `foo(std::string&& val)`. It is an lvalue of type "rvalue reference". Perfectly legal to take its address, and use its address, until the lifetime of `s` ends.