# Difference between auto&& and auto

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, rvalue-reference

So, I've made such a class, and launched main:

```
class my_class{
public:
    my_class(): status("constructor"){
        cout << "constructor" << endl;
    }
    my_class(my_class&& obj): status("move constructor"){
        cout << "move constructor" << endl;
    }
    my_class(const my_class& obj): status("copy constructor"){
        cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
    }
    my_class& operator=(my_class&& obj){
        cout << "move assignment" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    my_class& operator=(const my_class& obj){
        cout << "copy assignment" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    ~my_class(){
        cout << "destructor; " << "object made by: " << status << endl;
    }
    string status;
};

my_class&& fun1(my_class&& temp){
    cout << "inside fun1" << endl;
    return move(temp);
}

my_class fun2(my_class&& temp){
    cout << "inside fun2" << endl;
    return move(temp);
}

int main(){
    auto&& testing_var1 = fun1(my_class{});
    auto&& testing_var2 = fun2(my_class{});
    auto testing_var3 = fun1(my_class{});
    auto testing_var4 = fun2(my_class{});
    return 0;
}
```

And what I've got really suprised me:

```
constructor
inside fun1
constructor
inside fun2
move constructor
constructor
inside fun1
move constructor
constructor
inside fun2
move constructor
```

Why when the "testing_var3" is returned by fun1, the move constructor is used? Why there is such a difference, when the deduction of type is made by auto not auto&&?

I thought that move assignment would be used, but move constructor in fun1 is for me nonsense...

And why the move constructor is used in fun2? Shouldn't it be move assignment?

/EDIT:

I've added some extra code to constructors and destructors. Now I get:

```
constructor
inside fun1
destructor; object made by: constructor
constructor
inside fun2
move constructor
destructor; object made by: constructor
constructor
inside fun1
move constructor
destructor; object made by: constructor
constructor
inside fun2
move constructor
destructor; object made by: constructor
destructor; object made by: move constructor
destructor; object made by: move constructor
destructor; object made by: move constructor
```

And my next question is: Why the first variable is dangling reference and other don't? Why second variable isn't such a reference, as suggested @MattMcNabb ?

Comment: Assignment is not used here becuase, well, there are no assignments in the main function at all.

Comment: Note that `testing_var1` and `testing_var2` are dangling references (if you add destructor output you'll see that straight away) - there is no lifetime extension of temporary here

Comment: In 1st, I do understand, but still don't get why 2nd is dangling reference... `testing_var2` is constructed by move constructor, and deconstructed at the end of main, so it doesnt't look like to me as dangling reference...

Comment: You're right; `1` is a dangling reference but `2` is not. The rule is that an rvalue reference extends lifetime when bound to a *prvalue*, but not when bound to an *xvalue*. [Explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3716360/1505939)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why when the "testing_var3" is returned by fun1, the move constructor is used?

`testing_var3` is deduced as type `my_class`, therefore a constructor must be called to create a new `my_class` object. Since the right hand side is a temporary, the move constructor is chosen.

> Why there is such a difference, when the deduction of type is made by auto not auto&&?

If you use `auto&&` then you always declare a reference, and a constructor is not called when a reference to class is bound to an expression of the same class type, because no new object is created. `auto` never declares a reference.

> I thought that move assignment would be used, but move constructor in fun1 is for me nonsense...
>
> And why the move constructor is used in fun2? Shouldn't it be move assignment?

There is no assignment occurring; just *copy-initialization*. In

```
T x = e;
T x = braced-init-list;
```

assignment operators are not called, despite the appearance of the `=` token. It's initialization, not assignment. Assignment requires an already-constructed object to assign to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In first moment I didn't realize that there isn't any assignment-just initialization of variable.

Answer (score 0):

`testing_var3` is constructed by move ctor and for the last the return value is constructed by a move ctor...

There is no assignment in `fun2` only a returned value that need to be constructed/initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you read Scott Meyers' [blog](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) on "Universal References". auto&& can bind to an lvalue or an rvalue. In most situations, you won't need to use auto&&, unless you really know what you are doing.